# Divergence as a measure of class seperability. How to implement in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I have 50 attributes and 2 classes. I want to rank those attributes based on their divergence, which is described as:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urP0E.png)

I don't have the pdfs of the variables, since it's a real experiment. Do you have any recommendation on how to calculate the divergence? Are there any packages that could calculate it or do I have to do it manually?

Thank you

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that sympy might be what you're looking for.
The sympy documentation has a [tutorial](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html) explaining how to use